# Looking for pass method group as parameter

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, parameter-passing

I have problem with too much exact same code on buttons the diffrence is that im using diffrent method group. I want to do one function for all buttons to make code more simplified and readable. Thanks for any ideas and help. Here is how I see this:

```
private void Button1_Click()
    {
        //code
        Method1(string);
    }
    private void Button2_Click()
    {
        //exactly same code but using different method
        Method2(string);
    }

    private void MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons(Method method)
    {
        //same code
        method();
    }
Button1_Click => MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons(Method1(string);
Button2_Click => MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons(Method2(string);
```

Comment: Just link the same handler to different buttons. (Depending on your framework use commands).

Comment: Keep your two button-click handlers. Don't pass method to `MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons`. If Method1/Method2 need a value the code in MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons produces, let MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons return that value, then pass it into Method1/Method in your button-click handlers. Like for example `private void Button1_Click() { string s = StuffExecutedByAllButtons(); Method1(s); }`

Comment: Extract the 'Same code' into a method. Then you only need to call that method and your different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many of funcitons to pass func to parameters but I used Action  action its looks something like this:

```
private void MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons(Action <string> action)
{
    //code
    action(string);
}

Button1_Click => MyFunctionAsParamForAllButtons(FuncName);
```